# Mysql sum total downloads from one table and update it in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a table users and another table photographs. Photographs table contains column named `download` which contains the download of the photo.

`user_id` column in photograph contains the id of the users. I have created another column in users named download. I wanted to update it with the total downloads from the photographs column for the same id as in user_id

So `Photographs` table contains this

```
id  |  user_id  | download
----+-----------+----------
1   |  1        | 5
2   |  1        | 6
3   |  2        | 6
4   |  2        | 6
5   |  1        | 6
```

`Users` table contains

```
    id  |  download 
    ----+----------
    1   |  0        
    2   |  0
```

The final result should look like:

```
id  |  download 
----+----------
1   |  17        
2   |  12
```

I tried this it returns the `user_id` and its total downloads. How to update it in users table?

```
SELECT
    user_id, SUM(download) AS Total
FROM
    Photographs
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

Comment: does your user table already exist??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple. You need to use a sub select, like this:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users u, ( SELECT user_id, SUM(download) as dcount FROM photographs GROUP BY user_id) as p 
SET u.download = dcount WHERE u.id = p.user_id
";

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

You were already half ways there, well done.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect !!!